# Does neo4j-jdbc really need preparedstatement?

Tags: neo4j, prepared-statement

I am trying out neo4j-jdbc and wondering whether preparedstatement really brings benefit in terms of the performance on cypher execution since the underlying mechanism is no longer the RDMS we used to know.
Any advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neo4j has the same mechanism AS RDBMS, it's called "parameterized query".

It's important to use it, because Neo4j can reuse the query execution plan of the query, and that leads to better execution times (if you execute multi-times the same query).

Check the documentation : http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/

Cheers.